# Getting averages into a list from a csv file

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

```
import matplotlib
import csv
```

## the csv file below is of many years and tons of DBH

```
f = open("Species.csv")

reader = csv.reader(f)
```

## ------Initializations------

```
y1974 = []

y1983 = []

y1987 = []

y1989 = []

y1994 = []

y1999 = []

y2004 = []

y2009 = []

y2014 = []


dbhByYear = [y1974, y1983, y1987, y1989, y1994, y1999, y2004, y2009, y2014]



def average(alist):
    sum = 0
    for item in alist:
        sum += float(item)
    avg = sum / len(alist)
    return avg
```

## this allows the user to input a specific species of tree to look at

```
species = input("Enter abbreviation for species you would like to analyze: ")
```

## this removes the "999" within the file

```
for row in reader:
    if row[4] == species:
        if row[6]!='999':
            y1974.append(row[6])
        if row[7] != '999':
            y1983.append(row[7])
        if row[9] != '999':
            y1987.append(row[9])
        if row[11] != '999':
           y1989.append(row[11])
        if row[13] != '999':
           y1994.append(row[13])
        if row[15] != '999':
           y1999.append(row[15])
        if row[18]!= '999':
           y2004.append(row[18])
        if row[20] != '999':
           y2009.append(row[20])
        if row[23] != '999':
           y2014.append(row[23])
```

## these print the average DBH for each year

```
 print(average(y1989))
 print(average(y1994))
```

## This is the function i am using to get the dictionary

```
 averages = {}
 averages["y1989"]=average
```

My question is is how do you Create a dictionary with the years as keys and average DBH as values.

If anyone is confused (which i bet people will be as to what we are trying to do) please let me know and i will try and clear up questions you may have.

Comment: species = input("Enter abbreviation for species you would like to analyze: ")  This allows the user to pick what kind of species of tree they want to see

Comment: You might want to check out our page on [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE)

Comment: The species came from an excel file (.xlsx) that we converted to a csv file

Comment: Not really what I meant to ask. You need to give all information relevant to the question and nothing else. Make sure that you know exactly what you're asking for and specify that. As it stands this question will likely be removed for being too broad/unclear what you're asking.

Comment: okay so i changed my question to ask hopefully more specific question.  sorry this is my first time asking a question on this site.

Comment: Okay that is much more clear. Now what exactly is your problem? It seems you have already found a way to calculate the averages, why can't you put them in a dictionary?

Comment: okay so i just added the code i have tried to make a dictionary so far (i doubt it's correct as i am very new to python), but after running the program the only thing within the dictionary is the year and function average location.  For example this is the dictionary out put after being run...                
  {'y1989': <function average at 0x10ae7d9d8>}

Comment: See my answer below. In the future make sure that your questions follow community guidelines, or else they are probably going to be closed (I'm actually astounded this one didn't). The only reason I was willing to go so far with this is because it is your first question and you don't quite understand how to write a good question yet. No one will be as lenient the next time. Read through our [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) before asking another question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay! Your last edit showed me exactly where you went wrong! `average` is a function, so assigning it to a dictionary key does not apply that function to that dictionary key, but, in essence, "renames" the function (this glosses over a bit, but it's not relevant to your question).

So, to make it work the way you're expecting, you would need to change that last line to this:

```
averages["y1989"]=average(y1989)
```

just like you did in the print statement above it.

Comment: thanks also to print out the years we so far have had to individually input the print statements by year. Is there anyway to stream line that process because that I would assume work (kinda) for the dictionary too, like get all the years and averages of the inputted species into 1 dictionary.  So instead of it just being 1989 it would be all of them?

Comment: `for year, average in averages:` / `print(str(year) + ": " + str(average))`

Comment: Thanks that's definetly a good starting point to go off of, just gotta figure out the error im getting.  Thanks again for the leniency